# Building series of images in python

Tags: python, image, build, insert

I am trying to build an application that builds tool-strings by selecting and inserting pre-made png that are saved in a folder. The pngs need to be placed onto a canvas and built up one by one by selecting an image from a folder and placing onto the canvas in a grid like format.

I have including an example of the [toolstring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuhmj.jpg) I am trying to make. Currently this is being built manually in a photo manipulation software but I would like to automate the process in a stand alone python application.

Any pointers in the right direction would be grateful, I'm not sure what to google. (Relevant plugins, tutorials, examples). I have a small amount of experience in python programming.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look at this [Python library, PIL](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/handbook/tutorial.html)

Comment: Thank you, I want the application to run inside a GUI.